# How to find out who the ROM provider is?

Tags: android

I have an automatic bug reporting facility in my app that includes useful information for debugging.

One thing that I would like to include is the ROM provider. In particular I would like to know if the user is running a custom ROM and which, preferably even with the version number.

Any idea how to retrieve this information programmatically?

--- Taken from the Quintin (see below)

http://code.google.com/p/cyanogen-updater/source/browse/trunk/src/cmupdaterapp/utils/SysUtils.java#19:

```
public static String getReadableModVersion() { 
  String modVer = getSystemProperty(Constants.SYS_PROP_MOD_VERSION); 
  return (modVer == null || modVer.length() == 0 ? "Unknown" : modVer); 
}
```

Whereby the constant is this:

```
public static final String SYS_PROP_MOD_VERSION = "ro.modversion";
```

And here is the getSystemProperty();

```
public static String getSystemProperty(String propName){
            String line;
            BufferedReader input = null;
    try
    {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop " + propName);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()), 1024);
        line = input.readLine();
        input.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to read sysprop " + propName, ex);
            return null;
    }
    finally
    {
            if(input != null)
            {
                            try
                            {
                                    input.close();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception while closing InputStream", e);
                            }
            }
    }
    return line;
}
```

Could anybody with a CM ROM can run this for me?

Btw. Careful, this is GPL code. I for one can not use it.
Any easier or non-GPL way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is code in the [Cyanogen-Updater](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogen-updater/) project that has this functionality, although I think the rom information is provided by a prop file provided by the rom developer so i'm not sure if it will work universally.  I haven't investigated this thoroughly, but you can take a look at the source and figure it out.

Comment: I had a look. 

http://code.google.com/p/cyanogen-updater/source/browse/trunk/src/cmupdaterapp/utils/SysUtils.java#19

  public static String getReadableModVersion() {
    String modVer = getSystemProperty(Constants.SYS_PROP_MOD_VERSION);
                
  return (modVer == null || modVer.length() == 0 ? "Unknown" : modVer);
}

Whereby the constant is this:
public static final String SYS_PROP_MOD_VERSION = "ro.modversion";

Do you run Cyanogen? Could you execute that for me and tell me the result?

Comment: No formatting in the comments? Whatever I put it also on the top then.

Comment: Yes I do have a version of his rom running, and the result of mine is "CyanogenMod-4.0.4", however when run on an official SDK build via the emulator I do get "Unknown".  The `ro.modversion` is set in the build.prop file at /system/build.prop

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if there's a clear indicator of the provider, but you could inspect the contents of `/proc/version`. Here's the output for CyanogenMod 4.0.4:

> Linux version 2.6.29.6-cm4 (shade@toxygen) (gcc version 4.4.0 (GCC) ) #8 PREEMPT Fri Aug 28 20:30:25 EDT 2009

The hint here is the "cm4" suffix, which (*I believe*) stands for CyanogenMod 4 (plus the distinctive user@host bit, albeit less clear). For comparison, here's the version for the emulator running 1.6:

> Linux version 2.6.27-00110-g132305e (mikechan@cheetara.corp.google.com) (gcc version 4.2.1) #6 Mon Feb 2 12:47:38 PST 2009

You could also check the values for [`android.os.Build`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html). There isn't much info on `Build.TYPE`, but I'm assuming type "eng" stands for official build, and type "user" stands for home-made build, so that could be useful too.

Comment: I think I will go for the other approach with the system property. But thanks anyway.

Btw. I believe that the current, official, HTC hero rom runs an ENG build.

Comment: Looks like `Build.TYPE` isn't enough to determine if it's a custom ROM. I just tested it on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10 running Android 9, and it returned `user`.

Answer (score 3):

Custom ROMS tend to overwrite Build.DISPLAY. I've just checked with CheckRom REVOHD V6 and it worked.