# How to determine if OS is a custom ROM from an App?

Tags: android, digital-signature, rom

I'm developing an Android application, but I want to restrict my application to only be accessible by hardware that is not running a rooted/custom ROM. I know about Android's Forward Locking content protection, but would like to double check this protection from within my app. Is there any way to get the signature of the device along with a trusted signature of the ROM using android API's so that I lock my app out from Custom ROMs?

Answer (score 7):

There is no fail-proof way that I can think of, sorry. The main point of a ROM or root is that you can change whatever you want. Therefore, none of the Android API calls are safe from modifications e.g. there is no call that would 100% let you know you are running on a legit device.

Update: Check out [Google Safety Net](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNet), it may allow you to ensure that a device is non-modified. From what I read, safety net is supposed to let you check if a device is "compatible" with what google says are the corrent "android" APIs

Comment: Google Safety Net can easily be circumvented on most custom roms with Magisk: https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445

Comment: @FatTony not really. SafetyNet keeps changing and is now present in multiple proprietary bootloaders. From Google's perspective, preventing ROM hiding is a good thing for the app ecosystem, so they keep making SN harder to defeat. Search magisk for SN references and you'll see stuff like "verification should be coded deep into the bootloader, which is not that easy to crack. So the conclusion is that I will not spend that much time bypassing Safety Net in the future". While it is a cat-and-mouse game, Google have shown they are committed to preventing ROMs from hiding

Comment: This sucks for the ROM scene, but I've seen first hand that many big companies want to protect their application code/data from "rooted devices" and SN is Google's main answer to this. There are other answers (TEE apps), but "use SN" is IMO the correct technical answer to OP's question. Is it morally correct? That's up to each person, SN damages the ROM scene as more apps use SN to hide features, but it also enables more "security focused" apps (as long as you consider it OK for google to be the ultimate arbitrator of security). You can't get SN without passing CTS, so Google has lots of power

Answer (score 2):

This question has some information on determining whether a device is running a custom ROM:

[How to find out who the ROM provider is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547236/how-to-find-out-who-the-rom-provider-is)