# How can I check for custom ROM?

Tags: android, rom

I want to check in my device whether a custom ROM is installed or not.  I don't want my app to run if there is a custom ROM on any device.  How could I know this through code?

Comment: Custom ROM can installed only after rooting android device. And in rooting process there is an called Super User installed on device, so you have to check if there is superuser.apk installed then my be there is custom rom available on android device. You can check it through file object. `File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk"); return file.exists();`

Comment: @Meenal sharma every rom is custom rom bcoz android is open source and   device company creates own rom so expalin what you trying to do

Comment: Why would you want to block a custom ROM? From an user perspective, it is really annoying when developers do that!

Comment: @Chris i dnt wana block custom rom..i just want to restrict my app..not to install or run..when there is a custom rom in the device.

Comment: @raj the rom customized by device manufacturers call Stock Rom not custom rom

Answer (score 8):

```
System.getProperty("os.version"); // OS version
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK      // API Level
android.os.Build.DEVICE           // Device
android.os.Build.MODEL            // Model 
android.os.Build.PRODUCT          // Product
```

Use this and then compare it with the Google stock images.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547253/2606342) as well.

One more thing, almost 99% of all the custom ROMs are rooted so you could check whether the device is rooted or not.  The `RootTools` library offers simple methods to check for root:

```
RootTools.isRootAvailable()
```

Get the [RootTools library](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools).

Comment: Can you explain a bit about comparing installed custom rom sys property with android stock factory images? How you will get factory images details where device has custom rom?

Comment: Custom rom won't have the factory images, you've to get it yourself from the stock @ManishDubey just check that inside your app with the factory images.. Here images is not much concern about, for sure Device, Model and Product of a Custom ROM will differ from the stock one

Answer (score 0):

Could someone ask this question as a part of "**google's policy** supporters"?
Personally, I think that could be happen.
As I know and I can see, there are such of "supporters"!
 - *I mean **google's policy** to keep enforce the exposing the personal user's data and keeps control the market.*

Answer (score 0):

Try using Googles Saftynet service... It can be spoofed but not much users know how and do that. If you only detect root the app also doesn't run on stock Rom, when stock is rooted.

Answer (score -3):

You should check for the ROM name under the "About device".

Google the name of your ROM and you will get the results whether it is a custom ROM or not.

Comment: This question is about to check programmatically. Going on "About Device" section doesn't help to accomplish that.