# Check custom rom in android programmatically

Tags: android, mobile, rom

I want to check in my app that the device has custom ROM or not. With this I have enable and disable some features in my app. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Check these properties in your code and then compare it with the Google stock images.

```
System.getProperty("os.version"); // OS version
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK      // API Level
android.os.Build.DEVICE           // Device
android.os.Build.MODEL            // Model 
android.os.Build.PRODUCT          // Product
```

almost of all the custom ROMs are rooted so you can also check whether the device is rooted or not. Below is the code to check root.

```
    public static boolean isRooted() {

    // get from build info
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
    if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
      return true;
    }

    // check if /system/app/Superuser.apk is present
    try {
      File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
      if (file.exists()) {
        return true;
      }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      // ignore
    }

    // try executing commands
    return canExecuteCommand("/system/xbin/which su")
        || canExecuteCommand("/system/bin/which su") || canExecuteCommand("which su");
  }

  // executes a command on the system
  private static boolean canExecuteCommand(String command) {
    boolean executedSuccesfully;
    try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      executedSuccesfully = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      executedSuccesfully = false;
    }

    return executedSuccesfully;
  }
```

PS - emulator is a rooted devices. Test on actual device

Answer (score 1):

```
System.getProperty("os.version"); // OS version
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK      // API Level
android.os.Build.DEVICE           // Device
android.os.Build.MODEL            // Model 
android.os.Build.PRODUCT          // Product
```

Use this and then compare it with the Google stock images.One more thing, almost 99% of all the custom ROMs are rooted so you could check whether the device is rooted or not. The RootTools library offers simple methods to check for root:

RootTools.isRootAvailable()

You may refer below links for further details
[How to find out who the ROM provider is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547236/how-to-find-out-who-the-rom-provider-is/1547253#1547253)
And for RootTools use below link

https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools

Answer (score 0):

Try using Googles Saftynet service (it detects if bootloader is unlocked, to install a custom Rom bootloader must be unlocked)... It can be spoofed but not a lot users know how to do that. If you only detect root the app also doesn't run on stock Rom, when stock is rooted.